# Spring boot devtools Livereload server not starting when spring-devtools.properties is configured

Tags: spring-boot, livereload, spring-boot-devtools

I am running a spring boot application on an embedded tomcat server on eclipse in my local environment with spring dev tools enabled. And I also have spring web flow configured in the application. Below are the version details.

```
Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE
Spring Web Flow 2.4.4.RELEASE
```

The pom for dev-tools is configured as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

My devtools configuration for livereload and restart in "application.properties" under resources is

```
spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=true
spring.devtools.restart.additional-exclude=/webapp/**,WEB-INF/view/**
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true
```

With the above properties set, livereload and auto-restart work without any problems. But the spring-webflow related functionality doesn't work in the application.

Since its a known issue that spring-dev-tools and spring-web-flow don't play nice, I had to put this property as a workaround fix in "spring-devtools.properties" file under /resources/META-INF as shown below.

```
restart.include.spring=/spring-[\\s\\S]+\.jar
```

This property fixed the spring-web-flow problem but the livereload server doesn't start. The server console log as well doesn't show that it has started the livereload server on so and so port.

I am unable to pinpoint the what is causing this problem.

Can anyone help?

**Update:**
I can't seem to make this work. I think the workaround fix mentioned above is including the dev-tools classes as well in the Restart Classloader and hence preventing the livereload server from starting up.

Correct me If I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to start LiveReload server...

similar question here:
[Unable to start LiveReload server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667649/unable-to-start-livereload-server/50085157)

more info here: https://www.programmersought.com/article/11941784687/

## We can only use one per IDE.

Go to the Spring application.properties and set all others to false:

```
spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=false
```